# Terrafrom init fails with error - Invalid version constraint for provider azurerm

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure-as-code, azure-rm

When I run `terraform init` command in Azure cloud shell, I am getting below error:

> Initializing modules...
>
> Warning: Skipping backend initialization pending configuration upgrade
>
> The root module configuration contains errors that may be fixed by
>   running the configuration upgrade tool, so Terraform is skipping
>   backend initialization. See below for more information.
>
> Error: Invalid provider version constraint

Here is my tf file.

```
#############################################################################
# VARIABLES
#############################################################################

variable "resource_group_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "location" {
  type    = string
  default = "eastus"
}


variable "vnet_cidr_range" {
  type    = string
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

variable "subnet_prefixes" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["10.0.0.0/24", "10.0.1.0/24"]
}

variable "subnet_names" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["web", "database"]
}

#############################################################################
# PROVIDERS
#############################################################################

provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~> 1.x"
}

#############################################################################
# RESOURCES
#############################################################################

module "vnet-main" {
  source              = "Azure/vnet/azurerm"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  vnet_name           = var.resource_group_name
  address_space       = var.vnet_cidr_range
  subnet_prefixes     = var.subnet_prefixes
  subnet_names        = var.subnet_names
  nsg_ids             = {}

  tags = {
    environment = "dev"
    costcenter  = "it"

  }
}

#############################################################################
# OUTPUTS
#############################################################################

output "vnet_id" {
  value = module.vnet-main.vnet_id
}
```

Comment: Try to change the provider `azurerm` with a special version, without the x.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after removing azurerm version....

```
provider "azurerm" {

}
```